# Git: merge commits with history for a specific folder between branches

Tags: git, synchronization, directory, share, local

I'm new to **Git** and get stumbled upon sharing a specific folder between two (or multiple) branches in one repo.

for example, structure of the repo is following:

```
branch 'earth tests':
-solar system
--sun
--earth
--moon

branch 'mars tests':
-solar system
--sun
--mars
--fobos
--deimos

branch 'sun work':
-solar system
--sun
```

What I need to achieve is to share 'sun' folder between branches with all history of commits saved. So if I committed some changes in any branch to 'sun' folder it will add this commits to all branches with 'sun' folder preserving the original commit message.

In result the branch 'sun work' will contain all the history of the commits for folder 'sun' from all branches.

I tried to set 'sun' folder as subtree/subrepo but it seems that this doesn't work or I do not understand how to do it right. Ideal scenario will be git synchronizing branches any time the folder 'sun' gets commited.

Comment: You cannot do this with branches. Note, too, that Git does not *save* folders (directories) at all. Git only saves *files*. If a file lives in path `a/b/c`, and you check out a commit that contains that file, Git will, at that point, *create* `a/b` if necessary, first creating `a` if necessary. But it never *saved* either `a` or `a/b` here.

Comment: @torek So I could add a subrepo as folder from another repository but can't share files within the same repo? That is kinda sad.

Comment: It's not that you can't do it at all, it's that you can't do it with *branches*. A branch name is simply a pointer to a (single) commit. A commit is a snapshot of *all* files. Checking out any particular commit means "rearrange the index-and-work-tree so that they match the commit I just checked out" ... and that will make it match the *complete snapshot* in the new commit you select.

Comment: Hence, if you change some files (whose names happen to match `sun/*`) and commit, you're making a *new* commit with *every* file, in `sun/*`, `moon/*`, and so on. This new commit goes on *the current branch*. If you then check out some other branch (and hence some other commit), you'll have all the `sun/*` and `moon/*` and so on files from *that commit*. You would then have to re-update all the `sun/*` files and commit again on the new selected branch, to make a new snapshot there that has all the updated files.

Comment: @torek Could a hack like: "1) Find all commits that refer to folder 'sun' in one branch, 2) update to each commit in order, 3) replace/merge files in other branch with each commit found, 4) commit new state of the other branch with the same commit message from original" work?